# How to narrow down return types based on discriminants

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, discriminated-union

Say I have a function with an argument that can take only two values `type Value = "a" | "b"`. I now have a function which based on the value of that argument, should return a different result:

```js
type Value = "a" | "b";

function Method(value: Value){
  if(value === "a") return 1000;
  else return "word"
}

const Result = Method("a");
```

In theory, if my value is "a" (which could be inferred when calling the function with a constant value of "a") I would get back a number. If the value is "b", I'd expect a string.

What is wrong in this snippet and how could I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) as below:

```js
type Value = "a" | "b";

function Method(value: "a"): number;
function Method(value: "b"): string;
function Method(value: Value){
  if(value === "a") return 1000;
  else return "word";
}

const Result = Method("a");
```

Comment: Perfect! Function overloading did the job, with the only caveat that the return type of the implementation has to be defined as well, as the union of the above overloads. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a switch statement instead of an if and only acct in this 2 values:

```
switch (value) {
  case 'a':
    return 1000;
  case 'b':
    return 'word'
}
return null; //in case the value falls out the expected values but this is optional
```

Comment: Some feedback in how this is not a correct approach will be educating.